# Best way to Create an WebApp from Responsive Website

Tags: android, webview, responsive-design

I'm trying to Load Pages of my website into android `WebView` through Navigation Drawer and I have Few options to accomplish my task.

1. Show Site in Android `WebView` as it is.
2. Convert sites navigation into android `DrawerLayout Menu`.
3. Add Menu Items in android `DrawerLayout` Manually and load pages in `WebView` as Menu Item Selected.

**------------ Problems I found in Cases above-----------**

**Case 1 : Show Site in Android `WebView` as it is.**

It looks fine because the site is responsive. But It became to heavy and uncomfortable and It is not seems like an App.

**Case 2 : Convert sites navigation into android `DrawerLayout Menu` .**

I don't know if it can be done or not. Please give some suggestion If it can be done through some way. I have researched on this but couldn't find any solution.

**Case 3 : Add Menu Items in android `DrawerLayout` Manually and load pages in `WebView` as navigated.**

I have tried adding Menu Items in drawer manually as sites navigation menu and loaded different pages with different `URL` as `DrawerLayout`'s Item's selected. But the problem was What to do with Site's Navigation menu ?

[image: Sample Image of App]

Can I remove this `navigation` from my android app programmatically Or is there any other way ? I've tried loading desktop view forcefully. But it looked so weird and I know it's not the proper way of loading webpage in mobile.

**I will appreciate Any kind of Reference, suggestions or guides. Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third question you are asking, removing the web navigation item.

I have the idea that you may do some trick to the response of your website, before you call the webview method to load the data.

For example, assuming that you somehow get the xml source of the website you want to display in your app as **response**. And it should look like something:

```
<html>
<head>
(some code here)
</head>
<menu>
(some code here)
</menu>
...
...
</html>
```

Ya, and now you could try to remove the **menu** block within this source html. And later display it with

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("base_url_here", "new_html_source_without_menu", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

That's my idea.

And to be honest I don't really suggest you open a webview and load a link and try to make an app...It would be much better if you could get the API from the website(you could somehow know it, I have try some times and I get it with some tricks). Second method is that you could use some tools like **Jsoup** to parse the website content. When I was pretty new to Android I played with Jsoup and really enjoy the process.

BTW, I have to tell you that some website use Javascript to make the jumping method for the menu item. If you move your mouse to the menu item on the website(or just check the source code), you may see the code is is actually a javascript method but not a link pointing to somewhere. In this case it's much difficult to translate it into a native navigation item.

That's all I could help now. Happy coding :)

Comment: i've created an web API grabbed data from Api and inserted them into sqlite with the help of Service class. But another challenge was to clear up local database. App became to heavy with custom adapter and many databases. So I wanted to show the site as it is and saving it in cache. Anyway thanks for your great suggestion. I've seen many apps which uses webview and it seems really nice. then I realized that I was doing too weird process. If you have any experience on creating these kind of news app then can you share some general ideas how they are build ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I am currently making a side project, w which combine the webview and native components together. I suggest you do it the same way. More details: let's say u now get a list of news items via the api you got, then u could create the home activity using a recyclerview to display them as a list. Then u could build an onclicklistener to each item, so that when user click on item, will then open another activity(let's say detail_activity) inside there is an embedded webview will display the content of the news.

Answer (score 0):

Make bar disappears

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_gray</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GreenActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>

    <style name="GreenActionBarBase" parent="@style/Widget.THE_STYLE_YOU_WANT">
        <item name="android:background">#00c341</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GreenActionBar" parent="GreenActionBarBase"/>    

</resources>
```

Comment: Will it hide the site's bar ??

Comment: Yes, change the style. Is a  example